# Recharts 100% width is not working in Nextjs / Reactjs. It is not occupying the entire width and also act like a block

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I am using Recharts with Next.js and Tailwindcss, I copied a barchart code snippet in Recharts to create my own barchart too. I have to change the height to aspect for it to work. But the width 100% is not working at all. The barchart remain like a block and ocuppy only few width. Pls what am I suppose to do for me to make the barchart cover the 100% width of div?

Here is my code snippet.

```
const MyChart = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex shadow-md p-4 w-full pb-0 relative text-xs m-4">
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" aspect={2}>
        <AreaChart
          width={500}
          height={400}
          data={data}
          margin={{
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
          }}
        >
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
          <XAxis dataKey="name" />
          <YAxis />
          <Tooltip />
          <Area type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stackId="1" stroke="#8884d8" fill="#8884d8" />
          <Area type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stackId="1" stroke="#82ca9d" fill="#82ca9d" />
          <Area type="monotone" dataKey="amt" stackId="1" stroke="#ffc658" fill="#ffc658" />
        </AreaChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default display of div element is

> block

And block elements occupy 100% width of parent element. In this case you change display of div from block to flex so div element just occupy the width of its content so <ResponsiveContainer occupy 100%of width of this div

Answer (score 1):

Im struggling with the same and although I didn't find any clear and nice solution, I got a hack that works.

In short, when screen width changes, I change the key of ResponsiveContainer so that it rerenders with correct, 100% width of its parent. The value of key is not important, the important thing is that it should change after you resize, triggering component remounting, because new key === new component for React

Im debouncing to reduce the number of unneeded rerenders, just once after finished resizing is enough.

```html
const OverviewChart: FC<IOverviewChart> = ({ data }) => {
  const [chartWidth, setChartWidth] = useState(0);
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

  const debouncedSetChartWidth = useDebounce(setChartWidth, 100);

  useEffect(() => {
    debouncedSetChartWidth(width);
  }, [debouncedSetChartWidth, width]);

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer key={chartWidth} className={styles.element} width={"100%"} height={300}>
      ...
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};
```

here is the content of useWindowDimensions custom hook

```html
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export type TWindowDimensions = {
  width: number;
  height: number;
};

const getWindowDimensions = (): TWindowDimensions => ({
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
});

const useWindowDimensions = (): TWindowDimensions => {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState<TWindowDimensions>({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
    };

    handleResize();

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return windowDimensions;
};

export default useWindowDimensions;
```